# get error on cursor in sqlitedatabase for assigning data to listview

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Hi I am trying to display the data to ListView form database. But I got a error/force close. It shows error on Cursor class. I didn't get what was happened and where I was done a mistake. Please help me.

DatadisplayActivity.java:

```
public class DataDisplayActivity extends Activity {

private DbHelper mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;

private ArrayList<String> userId = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> u_url = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> u_uid = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> u_pass = new ArrayList<String>();

private ListView userList;
private AlertDialog.Builder build;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_display);

    userList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    mHelper=new DbHelper(this);

    findViewById(R.id.addnew).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserpageActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("update", false);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

     //click to update data
    userList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserpageActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("URL", u_url.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("UID", u_uid.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("PASS", u_pass.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("ID", userId.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("update", true);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    //long click to delete data
    userList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int arg2, long arg3) {

            build = new AlertDialog.Builder(DataDisplayActivity.this);
            build.setTitle("Delete " + u_url.get(arg2) + " " + u_uid.get(arg2)+" "+u_pass.get(arg2));
            build.setMessage("Do you want to delete ?");
            build.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                                    u_url.get(arg2) + " "
                                            + u_uid.get(arg2)
                                            + " is deleted.", 3000).show();

                            dataBase.delete(
                                    DbHelper.TABLE_SAVE,
                                    DbHelper.KEY_ID + "="
                                            + userId.get(arg2), null);
                            displayData();
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            build.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = build.create();
            alert.show();

            return true;
        }
    });

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    displayData();
    super.onResume();


}

/**
 * displays data from SQLite
 */
private void displayData() {
    dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DbHelper.TABLE_SAVE, null);

    userId.clear();
    u_url.clear();
    u_uid.clear();
    u_pass.clear();
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ID)));
            u_url.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_URL)));
            u_uid.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_UID)));
            u_pass.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_PASS)));
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    DisplayAdapter disadpt = new DisplayAdapter(DataDisplayActivity.this,userId, u_url, u_uid,u_pass);
    userList.setAdapter(disadpt);
    mCursor.close();
}
}
```

Error:

```
02-17 12:00:26.391: E/SQLiteLog(913): (1) no such table: saveinfo
02-17 12:00:26.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(913): Error inserting uid=srikanth password=srikanth url=www.facebook.com
02-17 12:00:26.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(913): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: saveinfo (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO saveinfo(uid,password,url) VALUES (?,?,?)
02-17 12:00:26.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(913):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-17 12:00:26.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(913):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
02-17 12:00:26.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(913):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
02-17 12:00:26.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(913):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-17 12:00:26.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(913):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-17 12:00:26.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(913):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
02-17 12:00:26.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(913):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
02-17 12:00:26.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(913):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
02-17 12:00:26.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(913):  at com.example.personal.UserpageActivity.saveData(UserpageActivity.java:126)
02-17 12:00:26.421: E/SQLiteDatabase(913):  at com.example.personal.UserpageActivity.onClick(UserpageActivity.java:70)
```

Comment: please post logcat also

Comment: hi nikis here is my logcat. iam sorry it is not a well formed, i dont know how to post the logcat. so  please excuse me and give me solution   based on this logcat information. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the root of error in your code is here:

```
com.example.personal.UserpageActivity.saveData(UserpageActivity.java:126)
```

I suppose you have opened DB (otherwise you would get `NullPointerException`), and it seems, per your stacktrace, that `no such table: saveinfo`. Please make sure you have this table in your DB and you've written table name correctly, preserving the case.

P.S. If this doesn't help you, show your **DbHelper.java** and `saveData()` method

Answer (score 0):

Your error code says,

```
02-17 12:00:26.391: E/SQLiteLog(913): (1) no such table: saveinfo
```

Could you please ensure you have such a table in your database?

Answer (score 0):

This is my DbHelper.java class..

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sri.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "login";
private static final String TABLE_CREATE ="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
```

"_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
"username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL);";

```
private static final String DB_ADMIN = "INSERT INTO "+TABLE_NAME+"values(1, admin, password);";

public static final String TABLE_SAVE="saveinfo";
public static final String KEY_ID="_id";
public static final String KEY_URL="url";
public static final String KEY_UID="uid";
public static final String KEY_PASS="password";

public static final String SCRIPT="CREATE TABLE"+TABLE_SAVE+"("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+KEY_URL+"TEXT NOT NULL,"
+KEY_UID+"TEXT NOT NULL,"+KEY_PASS+"TEXT NOT NULL);";



public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    System.out.println("In constructor");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try{
        //Create Database
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        //create admin account
        db.execSQL(DB_ADMIN);
        System.out.println("In onCreate");
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT);
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

```
}
```

}

Comment: please append this to your question